# Initializing trough constructor a 2-Dimensional pointer

Tags: pointers, multidimensional-array, constructor

I have created a class and tried to initialize a 2D pointer in my class constructor. Then I use a getter in my main.cpp but it doesn't worked. Building is successful but I end up with a value `0xcccccccc?` when I debug it. 
Here is my code.

Header

```
Asset {
    public:

    Asset(int numberAssets, int numberReturns); // Constructor
    //getter and setter
    double **getAssetReturnMatrix();

    ~Asset();

private:
    int _numberAssets, _numberReturns;
    double **_assetReturn;
};
```

Cpp file

```
#include "Asset.h"


Asset::Asset(int numberAssets, int numberReturns)
{
    // store data
    _numberAssets = numberAssets; // 83 rows  
    _numberReturns = numberReturns; // 700 cols

    //allocate memory for return matrix
    double **_assetReturn = new double*[_numberAssets]; // a matrix to  store the return data
    for (int i = 0; i<_numberAssets; i++)
        _assetReturn[i] = new double[_numberReturns];

}

Asset::~Asset()
{
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "read_data.h"
#include "Asset.h"

using namespace std;
int  main(int  argc, char  *argv[])
{
    //Create our class object

    int numberAssets = 83;
    int numberReturns = 700;
    Asset returnMatrix = Asset(numberAssets, numberReturns);

    //read the data from the file and store it into the return matrix
    string fileName = "asset_returns.csv";
    double ** data = returnMatrix.getAssetReturnMatrix();

    cout << data; // <--- Value 0xcccccccc? here

    //readData(data, fileName);

    return 0;
}
```

Could you please tell me where I am wrong?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I was created a new variable which had nothing to do with my private member `double **_assetReturn` defined in my h file, here:

```
//allocate memory for return matrix
double **_assetReturn = new double*[_numberAssets]; // a matrix to  store the return data
for (int i = 0; i<_numberAssets; i++)
    _assetReturn[i] = new double[_numberReturns];
```

Changed it to:

```
//allocate memory for return matrix
    this->_assetReturn = new double*[this->_numberAssets]; // a matrix to  store the return data
    for (int i = 0; i<this->_numberAssets; i++)
        this->_assetReturn[i] = new double[this->_numberReturns];
```

Worked fine now.